# Browserify - How to call function bundled in a file generated through browserify in browser

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify

I am new to nodejs and browserify. I started with this [link](http://browserify.org/) .

I have file main.js which contains this code

```
var unique = require('uniq');

var data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6];

this.LogData =function(){
console.log(unique(data));
};
```

Now I Install the uniq module with npm:

```
 npm install uniq
```

Then I bundle up all the required modules starting at main.js into a single file called bundle.js with the browserify command:

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

The generated file looks like this:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);throw new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'")}var f=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(f.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
var unique = require('uniq');

var data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6];

this.LogData =function(){
console.log(unique(data));
};

},{"uniq":2}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
"use strict"

function unique_pred(list, compare) {
  var ptr = 1
    , len = list.length
    , a=list[0], b=list[0]
  for(var i=1; i<len; ++i) {
    b = a
    a = list[i]
    if(compare(a, b)) {
      if(i === ptr) {
        ptr++
        continue
      }
      list[ptr++] = a
    }
  }
  list.length = ptr
  return list
}

function unique_eq(list) {
  var ptr = 1
    , len = list.length
    , a=list[0], b = list[0]
  for(var i=1; i<len; ++i, b=a) {
    b = a
    a = list[i]
    if(a !== b) {
      if(i === ptr) {
        ptr++
        continue
      }
      list[ptr++] = a
    }
  }
  list.length = ptr
  return list
}

function unique(list, compare, sorted) {
  if(list.length === 0) {
    return []
  }
  if(compare) {
    if(!sorted) {
      list.sort(compare)
    }
    return unique_pred(list, compare)
  }
  if(!sorted) {
    list.sort()
  }
  return unique_eq(list)
}

module.exports = unique
},{}]},{},[1])
```

**After including bundle.js file into my index.htm page, how do I call logData function ??**

Comment: Where do you want to call it? And why do you want to call it?

Comment: @arturgrzesiak: I want to utilize this function in one of my other project which i will be running in browser.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

By default, browserify doesn't let you access the modules from outside of the browserified code – if you want to call code in a browserified module, you're supposed to browserify your code together with the module. See http://browserify.org/ for examples of that.

Of course, you could also explicitly make your method accessible from outside like this:

```
window.LogData =function(){
  console.log(unique(data));
};
```

Then you could call `LogData()` from anywhere else on the page.

Comment: Thank you. This works. Does this mean, while creating functions instead of saying this.functionName, I should write window.functionName? Do we have any other work around for this? Any reasons for using window.functionName?

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite In a browser, everything you attach to the `window` object can be accessed from anywhere on the webpage.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. Is there any work around? otherwise before I browserify my code, I have to add `window.` in front of all the function i need to expose.

Comment: It is recommended to avoid window contamination like this; specifically because you are binding your memory-based components to a scope that doesn't dispose (or have a reasonable life-cycle).

Comment: *"you're supposed to browserify your code together with the module"* - Ugh, what if I want to do something like `onclick="someFunction()"`.  You can't possibly be arguing that that's a rare use-case!?!

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft certainly not rare, but somewhat unclean, especially when you consider that it's not compatible with a secure Content Security Policy

Comment: There's a serious lack of documentation anywhere for beginners on how to actually use Browserify on the client.

Comment: yeah, the documentation should clearly state that this is a design decision to be avoided, but provide a clear path to make it work when you don't have an alternative (in my case, using data from the template to populate a JS object)... thanks @thejh for pointing to a simple solution! ;)

Comment: I cannot even think of a situation where you WOULDN'T want to make your major functions available outside the module. How is this not default behavior? What kind of web application doesn't call functions?

Answer (score 115):

The key part of bundling standalone modules with Browserify is the `--s` option. It exposes whatever you export from your module using node's `module.exports` as a global variable. The file can then be included in a `<script>` tag.

You only need to do this if for some reason you need that global variable to be exposed. In my case the client needed a standalone module that could be included in web pages without them needing to worry about this Browserify business.

Here's an example where we use the `--s` option with an argument of `module`:

```
browserify index.js --s module > dist/module.js
```

This will expose our module as a global variable named `module`.
[Source](http://learnjs.io/blog/2014/02/06/creating-js-library-builds-with-browserify-and-other-npm-modules/).

**Update:**
Thanks to @fotinakis. Make sure you're passing `--standalone your-module-name`. If you forget that `--standalone` takes an argument, Browserify might silently generate an empty module since it couldn't find it.

Hope this saves you some time.

Comment: I am trying to browserify babelified ES6 code. But the standalone object is empty when I try to console it in browser. Simple ES6 code without any modules works fine in standalone mode. Any pointers on this?

Comment: @jackyrudetsky no idea, I would recommend add a question on SO, sounds like an interesting issue. could be related to this. https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1357

Comment: @jackyrudetsky Make sure you're passing `--standalone your-module-name`. If you forget that --standalone takes an argument, browserify might silently generate an empty module since it couldn't find it.

Comment: @fotinakis It was actually an issue in Browserify https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1537

Comment: IMO this should be the accepted answer. If you are using a global function, it is much better to have your own namespace than to hang every function off of window.

Comment: @VictorB all global variables in Javascript are elements of window, so both methods achieve the same thing (adding the global variables to window)

Comment: If you are using `watchify` to re-bundle each time your code changes, you can use the `--s modulename` options with it as well, i.e.:
`watchify test~/bundletest.js --s BUNDY -o test~/bundled_bundletest.js -v`. Here my module is named `BUNDY`.

Answer (score 57):

@Matas Vaitkevicius's [answer with Browserify's standalone option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296094/browserify-how-to-call-function-bundled-in-a-file-generated-through-browserify/28805578#28805578) is correct (@thejh's [answer using the window global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23296263/6157047) also works, but as others have noted, it pollutes the global namespace so it's not ideal). I wanted to add a little more detail on how to use the standalone option.

In the source script that you want to bundle, make sure to expose the functions you want to call via module.exports. In the client script, you can call these exposed functions via **<bundle-name>.<func-name>**. Here's an example:

My **source file src/script.js** will have this:
 `module.exports = {myFunc: func};`

My **browserify command** will look something like this:
 `browserify src/script.js --standalone myBundle > dist/bundle.js`

And my **client script dist/client.js** will load the bundled script
`<script src="bundle.js"></script>`
and then call the exposed function like this:
`<script>myBundle.myFunc();</script>`

---

There's no need to require the bundle name in the client script before calling the exposed functions, e.g. <strike>`<script src="bundle.js"></script><script>var bundled = require("myBundle"); bundled.myFunc();</script>`</strike> isn't necessary and won't work.

In fact, just like all functions bundled by browserify without standalone mode, the [require function won't be available outside of the bundled script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28696732/6157047). Browserify allows you to use some Node functions client-side, but *only in the bundled script itself*; it's not meant to create a standalone module you can import and use anywhere client-side, which is why we have to go to all this extra trouble just to call a single function outside of its bundled context.

Comment: Wow! Finally a practical example.

Comment: Good example, but as far as "it pollutes the global namespace therefore not ideal" does not follow automatically, it may be acceptable if it's only one function; Just smoke and mirrors, even `myBundle` gets attached to the window object,  `window.myBundle.myFunc()` instead of window.myFunc()

Comment: There should be extra points for people who give end-to-end examples.

Comment: That is how documentation should be written

Comment: Not working at my side, this is [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406191/browserify-not-working-with-module-exports-even-with-standalone-option).

Answer (score 8):

I just read through the answers and seems like nobody mentioned the use of the global variable scope? Which is usefull if you want to use the same code in node.js and in the browser.

```
class Test
{
  constructor()
  {
  }
}
global.TestClass = Test;
```

Then you can access the **TestClass** anywhere.

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script>
var test = new TestClass(); // Enjoy!
</script>
```

**Note:** The TestClass then becomes available everywhere. Which is the same as using the window variable.

Additionally you can create a decorator that exposes a class to the global scope. Which is really nice but makes it hard to track where a variable is defined.

Comment: As you yourself say, adding the function to `global` produces the same effect as adding to `window`, which was already covered by thejh. This answer adds no new information.

Comment: @GalenLong maybe you forgot that there is no window variable in node.js? And some libraries that target node and browser may want to use global instead. My answer got a few upvotes and is not in minus yet so i think its informative for others if not for you.

Comment: You're right, @Azarus. There were two other duplicate answers on the page and I incorrectly included yours in with the bunch. My apologies.

Comment: just want to note that the hanging parens here is a very bad practice for javascript, for example: apply this pattern to the return keyword and prepare to cry. e.g `return {}` but drop the opening curly brace down to the next line.

Comment: @Sgnl i have no clue what are you talking about sorry. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Azarus I created a fiddle to demonstrate what I mean - https://jsfiddle.net/cubaksot/1/

Comment: I can only say that not knowing the syntax of javascript and keeping braces in a new line has 0 to do with bad practice.. braces in new line actually make code more readable imho. But it's up to you how you write your code and it has nothing to do with the quality of the answer. It's really tabs or spaces

Comment: @Azarus except in this case it isn't a preference, in my jsfiddle example case it breaks code, I mean, that it produces unexpected results. With "Spaces vs. tabs" argument, at least your code isn't broken. If  you drop the opening parenthesis to the next line below the `return` keyword statement, your object (or array, or any opening token...) will NOT get returned out of the function. this is an issue specifically how Javascript and the `return` keyword works with this style of code formatting.

Comment: @Azarus Actually, if you revisit the jsfiddle now there is a linter in-place and it's calling out the line break after the `return` statement.

Comment: You don't put braces in a new line for a return statement? And you can put braces in a new line after a function definition?

Comment: You're arguing... Please stop bothering with this it adds no value to the answer

Comment: @Azarus, how to "create a decorator that exposes a class" ? as per last part of your answer.

Comment: have a look at typescript decorators it's fairly simple. Or create a question and i'll answer there with code samples. The channel here is just not right.

Answer (score 6):

**Minimal runnable example**

This is basically the same as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43215928/895245 but with concrete files that will allow you to just run and easily reproduce it yourself.

This code is also available at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/browserify-hello-world

index.js

```
const uniq = require('uniq');

function myfunc() {
  return uniq([1, 2, 2, 3]).join(' ');
}
exports.myfunc = myfunc;
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Browserify hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
</body>
</div>
<script src="out.js"></script>
<script>
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = browserify_hello_world.myfunc();
</script>
</html>
```

Node.js usage:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const browserify_hello_world = require('./index.js');

console.log(browserify_hello_world.myfunc());
```

Generate `out.js` for browser usage:

```
npx browserify --outfile out.js --standalone browserify_hello_world index.js
```

Both the browser and the command line show the expected output:

```
1 2 3
```

Tested with Browserify 16.5.0, Node.js v10.15.1, Chromium 78, Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: The `exports.myfunc.= myfunc` portion of this was absolutely critical and missed in other answers.

Answer (score 5):

Read README.md of browserify about `--standalone` parameter
or google "browserify umd"

Comment: This is more a hint on where to find an answer than an answer.

Comment: this lead me to the solution I was looking for for two days (how to use browserify output from a require.js environment). thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Whole concept is about wrapping.

### 1.) Alternative - Object "this"

for this purpose I'll assume you have "only 1 script for whole app `{{app_name}}`" and "1 function `{{function_name}}`"

add function `{{function_name}}`

```
function {{function_name}}(param) { ... }
```

to object `this`

```
this.{{function_name}} = function(param) { ... }
```

then you have to name that object to be available - you will do it add param "standalone with name" like others advised

so if you use ["watchify" with "browserify"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watchify) use this

```
var b = browserify({
    ...
    standalone: '{{app_name}}'
});
```

or command line

```
browserify index.js --standalone {{app_name}} > index-bundle.js
```

then you can call the function directly

```
{{app_name}}.{{function_name}}(param);
window.{{app_name}}.{{function_name}}(param);
```

### 2.) Alternative - Object "window"

add function `{{function_name}}`

```
function {{function_name}}(param) { ... }
```

to object `window`

```
window.{{function_name}} = function(param) { ... }
```

then you can call the function directly

```
{{function_name}}(param);
window.{{function_name}}(param);
```

Answer (score 3):

To have your function available from both the HTML and from server-side node:

**main.js:**

```
var unique = require('uniq');

function myFunction() {
    var data = [1, 2, 2, 4, 3];
    return unique(data).toString();
}
console.log ( myFunction() );

// When browserified - we can't call myFunction() from the HTML, so we'll externalize myExtFunction()
// On the server-side "window" is undef. so we hide it.
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.myExtFunction = function() {
        return myFunction();
    }
}
```

**main.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="bundle.js"></script>
    <head>
    <body>
        Result: <span id="demo"></span>
        <script>document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myExtFunction();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Run:**

```
npm install uniq
browserify main.js > bundle.js
```

and you should get same results when opening main.html in a browser as when running

```
node main.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

1. Let plugin [browserify-bridge](https://github.com/DeepElement/browserify-bridge) auto-export the modules to a generated entry module. This is helpful for SDK projects or situations where you don't have to manually keep up with what is exported.
2. Follow a pseudo-namespace pattern for roll-up exposure:

First, arrange your library like this, taking advantage of index look-ups on folders:

```
/src
--entry.js
--/helpers
--- index.js
--- someHelper.js
--/providers
--- index.js
--- someProvider.js
...
```

With this pattern, you define entry like this:

```
exports.Helpers = require('./helpers');
exports.Providers = require('./providers');
...
```

> Notice the require automatically loads the index.js from each respective sub-folder

In your subfolders, you can just include a similar manifest of the available modules in that context:

```
exports.SomeHelper = require('./someHelper');
```

This pattern scales really well and allows for contextual (folder by folder) tracking of what to include in the rolled-up api.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call your function from the html file like this:

main.js: (will be in bundle.js)

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('build-file')
        .addEventListener('click', buildFile)

}
function buildFile() {
 ...
}
```

index.html:

```
<button id="build-file"">Build file</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
window.LogData =function(data){
   return unique(data);
};
```

Call the function simply by `LogData(data)`

This is just a slight modification to [thejh's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492364/thejh) answer but important one

Comment: This modification is irrelevant to the question asker's concerns and doesn't add any new information given the already existing answers.

Answer (score -2):

For debugging purposes I added this line to my code.js:

```
window.e = function(data) {eval(data);};
```

Then I could run anything even outside the bundle.

```
e("anything();");
```