# Including browserify-ed js in polymer component; missing 'require'

Tags: polymer, browserify

What I'm trying to do is define a module of utility functions, browserify it
and use it in a polymer component. Since this post:
[require is not defined error with browserify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696511/require-is-not-defined-error-with-browserify)
makes it clear that 'require' is only defined within the scope of the bundle (xx.js), I need
help figuring out how to access my exported function.

Here is the gist:

file: x.js

```
module.exports = function() {console.log("hi");}
```

I run

```
browserify x.js> xx.js
```

file xx.js (edited)

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require==...
  module.exports = function() {console.log("hi");}
},{}]},{},[1]);
```

My polymer component (edited)

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<script type="text/javascript" src="xx.js"></script>

<dom-module id="Hello-app">
  <template> </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'Hello-app',
      ready: function() {/* how do I access the function here, so it prints "hi" */}
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I should have read the docs for browserify more carefully.
I just needed the '-r' option, like so:

```
  browserify -r ./x.js:hello > xx.js
```

and now I can modify the ready: line to read

```
  ready: function() {require('hello')()},
```