# How to access the code in client side from the bundle produced by webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I am very new to webpack. I configured webpack to bundle all js files and using it in an html file as an attempt to learn es6.

Now i have a function in './app/index.js' file

```
export function oops() {
  console.log("oops");
}
```

in a file index.js. My webpack config looks like

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      debug: false
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules|dist/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

If try to access to access the method oops() in a button click event

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="oops()"/>
```

the browser throws the error,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: oops is not defined.

I could not figure out myself why is it like this. I found this later [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296094/browserify-how-to-call-function-bundled-in-a-file-generated-through-browserify)

And this in index.js file

```
window.oops = function(){
  console.log("oops");
};
```

Is working. Is there any other way to do it? And also why is it webpack is not allowing to access the methods defined it outside?

Comment: Is your function in another JS file? If so you need to import the file to your index.js

Comment: Its in the same file.

Comment: You won't need to export the function if it's already in your index.js file

Comment: I tried with/without exporting the function.

Comment: Hmm, it will work if you write the onClick event within index.js

Comment: sorry @DeclanPossnett could you please give an example. I couldn't understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139081/discussion-between-declanpossnett-and-shansfk).