# Function from Browserify not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, httprequest, browserify

trying to run a function I previously run in node in plain web js without using the node execution. Can't figure out why the postOrderMarket function isn't found.

[image]

```
  <body>
    <div class="main">
    </div>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="res/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="res/bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".main").click(function() {
  postOrderMarket(100);
});
</script>
```

tiny part of bundle.js code

```
[function(require,module,exports){
    var request = require('request');
    var crypto = require('crypto');


      module.exports = function postOrderMarket(amount) {
        var verb = 'POST',
          path = '/api/v1/order',
          expires = new Date().getTime() + (60 * 1000),
          data = {symbol:"XBTUSD",side:"Buy",orderQty:amount,ordType:"Market"};
```

Comment: you need to require or import that module some how.

Comment: Which module? And.. some how?..

Comment: your bundlejs defines an module. `postOrderMarket` is part of that, not the global scope.

Comment: Shouldn't the module.exports solve that?

Comment: Is there any difference between `module.exports = function postOrderMarket(){}` and `module.exports.postOrderMarket = function(){}`?  I usually use the second one.

Comment: Changed to `module.exports.postOrderMarket = function(amount)`, didn't do much

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296094/browserify-how-to-call-function-bundled-in-a-file-generated-through-browserify